# How to insert parent node in XML through Python?

Tags: python, xml, pdf, tags, elementtree

I have an XML file structured like this and I want to insert the tag "newline" every time there is a certain distance in the coordinates (example here, in the file they are all different) provided:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pages>
    <page id="1" bbox="0.000,0.000,462.047,680.315" rotate="0">
        <textbox id="0" bbox="179.739,592.028,261.007,604.510">
            <textline bbox="179.739,592.028,261.007,604.510">
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">C</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum-it"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.333">A</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum-it"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.333">P</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum-it"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.333">I</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">T</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">O</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">L</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">O</text>
                <text></text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">I</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">I</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">I</text>
                <text></text>
            </textline>
        </textbox>
    </page>
</pages>
```

However, my code doesn't work as the tree I printed I find no traces of newline. It should be wrapping the text tag until the next one, like:

```
<newline><text></text></newline><newline><text></text></newline>
```

etc.

The code is:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import lxml.etree as etree
tree = ET.parse("fe2.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
node = ET.Element('newline')


for child in root.iter():
    if child.tag == 'text':
        #print(child.tag, child.attrib.items())
        for name, value in child.attrib.items():
                if name == 'bbox':
                        value = tuple(value.split(","))
                        x1 = float(value[0])
                        x2 = float(value[2])
                        distance = x2 - x1
                        if distance > 10:
                                root.insert(3, node)
                                xml_str = ET.tostring(root, encoding='unicode')
                                print(xml_str)
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do your task, it is easier to use *lxml* instead of *ElementTree*.
So I used the followint imports:

```
import lxml.etree as etree
from lxml.builder import E
```

The second import provides a factory of new elements.

To facilitate identification of elements, I slightly changed numeric values
in the source file (fractional parts after *191.*).

To get pretty printing with newlines, I read source file as follows:

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = etree.parse('input.xml', parser)
root = tree.getroot()
```

To wrap a **sequence** of "good" elements in a **single** *newline* element,
proceed as follows:

1. Define a function to remove an element from a parent by its index
   and return this element:

   ```
   def removeByIdx(parent, idx):
       currElem = parent[idx]   # The indicated element
       parent.remove(currElem)  # Remove it from the parent
       return currElem          # Return the index and element
   ```
2. Define a function to wrap children of *line* (a parent) with given indices
   in a *newline* element:

   ```
   def wrap(line, idxList):
       if len(idxList) == 0:
           return    # No elements to wrap
       # Take the first element from the original location
       idx = idxList.pop(0)     # Index of the first element
       elem = removeByIdx(line, idx) # The indicated element
       # Create "newline" element with "elem" inside
       nElem = E.newline(elem)
       line.insert(idx, nElem)  # Put it in place of "elem"
       while len(idxList) > 0:  # Process the rest of index list
           # Value not used, but must be removed
           idxList.pop(0) 
           # Remove the current element from the original location
           currElem = removeByIdx(line, idx + 1)
           nElem.append(currElem)  # Append it to "newline"
   ```
3. After reading the source XML tree, run:

   ```
   for line in root.iter('textline'):
       idxList = []
       for elem in line:
           bbox = elem.attrib.get('bbox')
           if bbox is not None:
               tbl = bbox.split(',')
               distance = float(tbl[2]) - float(tbl[0])
           else:
               distance = 100  # "Too big" value
           if distance < 10:
               par = elem.getparent()
               idx = par.index(elem)
               idxList.append(idx)
           else:  # "Wrong" element, wrap elements "gathered" so far
               wrap(line, idxList)
               idxList = []
       # Process "good" elements without any "bad" after them, if any
       wrap(line, idxList)
   ```

Then I printed the result tree:

```
print(etree.tostring(root, encoding='unicode', pretty_print=True))
```

getting:

```
<pages>
  <page id="1" bbox="0.000,0.000,462.047,680.315" rotate="0">
    <textbox id="0" bbox="179.739,592.028,261.007,604.510">
      <textline bbox="179.739,592.028,261.007,604.510">
        <newline>
          <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="191.740,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">C</text>
          <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum-it" bbox="191.741,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.333">A</text>
          <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum-it" bbox="191.742,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.333">P</text>
          <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum-it" bbox="191.743,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.333">I</text>
          <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="191.744,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">T</text>
          <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">O</text>
          <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="191.746,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">L</text>
          <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="191.747,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">O</text>
        </newline>
        <text/>
        <newline>
          <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="191.748,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">I</text>
          <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="191.749,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">I</text>
          <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="191.750,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">I</text>
        </newline>
        <text/>
      </textline>
    </textbox>
  </page>
</pages>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, but it wasn't exactly what I was looking for, because newline element wraps only one text element, while I would like to wrap multiple ones based on the next newline element. So basically every time there is the distance > 10, a new tag is inserted and is closed only when there is a newline again. Like <newline>[multiple text tags]</newline><newline>[text tags]</newline>

Comment: I changed my solution to wrap a **sequence** of "good" elements in a **single** *newline* element.